# What is $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q))$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automorphisms of projective special linear group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26882/automorphisms-of-projective-special-linear-group)

I'm sure this is well known, but I don't know where to look up such things.

What is $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q))$ for $q$ a power of a prime? More important to me than what the automorphisms are is what the isomorphism class of $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q))$ is.